# have to double tap in uitableviewcell for open view

Tags: ios, uitableview, didselectrowatindexpath

I have a grouped table view with 2 sections. Section number 1 is hidden, and the section open when you tap in the sections header. But when I want to open a view by tapping in the cells in section 1 I need to double tap for open it. But in section 0 I only need 1 tap. 
I based my open/close section in the Apple tutorial.

The didSelectRowAtIndexPath method don't register the first tap at the cell.

The method looks something like this:

```
-(void)tableview:(UITableView*)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath{
     [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
     if(indexPath.section == 0 && indexPath.row == 0)
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:trainingController animated:YES];
     else if(indexPath.section == 1 && indexPath.row ==0)
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:newsController animated:YES];
}
```

This is pseudocode, so might not be a working code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I hide both section it works with only 1 tap in both section. So if you want to hide a part of a section in uitableview is better to hide all, or you will have different interactions with the sections.

Answer (score 0):

Ur question is not clear.
If "didSelectRowAtIndexPath method don't register the first tap at the cell" is not registered
Inherit  protocol and set yourTableview.delegate=self;

Comment: Is quite clear, if the method react on the first tap in section 0 and on the second tap in section 1 is logical that the delegate it set to it self. Anyway, the class inherit from UITableViewController and not UIViewController.